# Outlook PST files that are in use

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to collect all the paths of the Outlook PST files that are currently in use. From what I can find on the internet the following code is supposed to do this:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$Namespace = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$Namespace.Stores
#or
$Namespace.Session.Stores
```

Every time I try this I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Exception from HRESULT: 0xEF640111.
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Is Outlook running at the time your code is executed?

Comment: Yes it is. I can even see the small pop-up asking to `Allow` this action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be when you are behing a VPN and one of the locations of your PST file paths can't be reached. Due to drive letters not being mapped automatically behind a VPN for example.

In that case MS Outlook can't even open the PST and also throws an error when you just click on the PST file in the GUI.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$outlook.Session.Stores | where { ($_.FilePath -like '*.PST') } | format-table DisplayName, FilePath -autosize
```